# Remove Highchart line when no value

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/vbLdsodu/

How do  i remove or hide the line after july? I want the date axis to continue but don't show the line where the values is 0.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `0` with `null` in the data which will then keep the axis listing the months, but stop the line from drawing.

It's also possible to do this part way through the graph and the line will draw from the next data point.

Comment: Thank you gabe3886!